# Spring MVC не видит страничек - 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Как настроить MVC?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class WebAppConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ViewsConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }
}
=========================================
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ViewsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("/WEB-INF/views/login");
        registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("/WEB-INF/views/register");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver());
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вылетает с ошибкой 404

Answer (score 0):

В текущей конфигурации есть как минимум одна большая проблема с тем как задается конфигурация view, а именно путь к `html` файлам.

`setViewName` задает URL path, т.е. часть URL так, как его вводите в браузере. Т.е. если полный URL для страницы - `http://localhost:8080/login`, то указывать имя нужно так:

```
 registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
```

А вот место, где в `webapp` находяться файлы указывается в `InternalResourceViewResolver`:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

Comment: Я так тоже пробовала(  и с jstl.сlass пробовала, выносить views в resources пробовала и указывать как classpath: потом. Не хочет меня радовать)

Comment: Еще пробовала и вовсе удалить viewResolver и  миксовать setViewControllers с контроллерами